# Programmatically Adding Images to Liferay Document Library version 6.1

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In Liferay6.1 I want to add images programmatically into Document Library?

This is my main method that I want to add an image into document library by it :

```
public class ImgGallery {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SystemException, FileNotFoundException {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        File srcfile = new File("C:\\Users\\my-pc\\Pictures\\extra\\myPhoto.jpg");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcfile);
        long repositoryId = 10180;
        long folderId = 10651;
        Map<String, Fields> fieldsMap = new HashMap<String, Fields>();
        DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(
              10196, repositoryId, repositoryId, folderId,
              "filename", MimeTypesUtil.getContentType("behnaz.jpg"),
              "title", "description", "changeLog", 0, fieldsMap,
              srcfile, null, bytes.length, serviceContext
        );
    }
}
```

This doesn't work - I don't know what arguments to supply to `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry`?

Comment: What problem you have in arguments?

Comment: @Lucky Boy, with thiese arguments : ServiceContext- file-inputstream Can you help me more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding a file to Liferay document library

You will need a folder, that you can create it in liferay control panel, my folder is TestFolder. You search for it with DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFolder. You need the  dlfileentrytypes. I hope we will understand the rest from the. You need to add the fileentry and after that you need to update it to be approved.

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);
File file = uploadRequest.getFile("uploadFile");
DLFileEntry fileEntry = null;
Long lessonId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "lid");
Lesson lll = LessonLocalServiceUtil.getLesson(lessonId);
String lesName = URLEncoder.encode(lll.getName(themeDisplay.getLocale()));
Date da = new Date();
String ext = FileUtil.getExtension(file.getName());
String dat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(da);

String title = lesName + "-" + dat + "." + ext;
long portraitId = themeDisplay.getUser().getPortraitId();
byte[] imageBytes = FileUtil.getBytes(file);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
PortletPreferences preferences = request.getPreferences();
String nameRo=uploadRequest.getParameter("nameRO");
String nameEn=uploadRequest.getParameter("name");

DLFolder dlFolder = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 0, "TestFolder");
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(DLFileEntry.class.getName(), request);
List<DLFileEntryType> tip = DLFileEntryTypeLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryTypes(DLUtil.getGroupIds(themeDisplay));

fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(themeDisplay.getUserId(), 
        themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 
        themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 
        dlFolder.getFolderId(), 
        file.getName(),
        MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file), 
        title, 
        request.getParameter("name"), 
        "", 
        tip.get(0).getFileEntryTypeId(), 
        null, 
        file, 
        is, 
        file.getTotalSpace(), 
        serviceContext);

DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(
        themeDisplay.getUserId(), 
        fileEntry.getFileEntryId(),
        file.getName(), 
        MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file), 
        title,
        "", 
        "", 
        true, 
        tip.get(0).getPrimaryKey(), 
        null, 
        file, 
        is,
        file.getTotalSpace(), 
        serviceContext);
```

EDIT : 
To acces the fileentry download url you can use

```
DLFileEntry dlf = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getDLFileEntry(f.get(i).getFileEntryId());
<a href='<%=themeDisplay.getPortalURL()+"/c/document_library/get_file?uuid="+DL.getUuid()+"&groupId="+themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId() %>' download>
Download </a>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was the most confusing java formatting I have ever seen. Your variable naming is is very strange too, but I try not to touch that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to call this API function from a commandline? (as the method `main` implies): You can't just startup a JVM and call Liferay API functions as no initialization is done yet.

You'll need to call API functions (esp. on *Local* services)  from a webapplication - e.g. a portlet or a hook - this typically does not happen from a main method.

Edit: Take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.html#addFileEntry%28long,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.util.Map,%20java.io.File,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29), granted, this does not give you many clues other than the argument names, but if you go through these and see the [implementation](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/src-html/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/impl/DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.html#line.113) as well, there are some things that might be worth trying/checking:

- Make sure, `userId` is a valid id for a user.
- Make sure that your value for `groupId` and `repositoryId` is valid as well - e.g. it needs to be the id for a site.
- Same for `folderId`: Make sure that it's a valid id for a folder. For this example we don't know how you came up with the value.
- You're giving 0 for the size (`bytes.length`)
- I'm guessing that the file you hardcoded actually exists? Make extra *extra* sure that you don't have a typo in file- or foldername

If this doesn't solve your problem, let us know what exact problem you have with your arguments: "I have a problem" is not really enough information for any meaningful help

Comment: exactly I want to upload images into a exact folder that I created in document library by a portlet. I think for some part that related to add image into that folder I can use  "DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry()" in my portlet. Is it right? Or my idea is false????????/